# Efficient Data Structure for Insertion

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, insertion

I'm looking for a data structure (array-like) that allows fast (faster than O(N)) arbitrary insertion of values into the structure. The data structure must be able to print out its elements **in the way they were inserted**. This is similar to something like List.Insert() (which is too slow as it has to shift every element over), except I don't need random access or deletion. Insertion will always be within the size of the 'array'. All values are unique. No other operations are needed.

For example, if Insert(x, i) inserts value x at index i (0-indexing). Then:

- Insert(1, 0) gives {1}
- Insert(3, 1) gives {1,3}
- Insert(2, 1) gives {1,2,3}
- Insert(5, 0) gives {5,1,2,3}

And it'll need to be able to print out {5,1,2,3} at the end.

I am using C++.

Comment: what do you mean by "array like"?

Comment: Do you have requirements regarding the complexity of traversing the data structure?

Comment: @juanchopanza I mean on the surface, it should act like a linear array. It should keep the elements in the way in which i've inserted them.

Comment: @LucTouraille So insertion should be sublinear (O(lgN) etc.), but outputting the contents of the array doesn't have to be very fast (O(N) or O(NlgN) is fine).

Comment: In that case what is wrong with std::list?

Comment: @juanchopanza If I'm not mistaken, std::list gives O(1) for insertion IF u have a pointer (iterator) to the index you are inserting to. However, getting that pointer requires a linear search.

Comment: @Peter you're absolutely right, my bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). Another option should be [tiered vector](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/papers/tiered-vector.pdf). The skip list performs inserts at const O(log(n)) and keeps the numbers in order. The tiered vector supports insert in O(sqrt(n)) and again can print the elements in order.

EDIT: per the comment of amit I will explain how do you find the k-th element in a skip list:

For each element you have a tower on links to next elements and for each link you know how many elements does it jump over. So looking for the k-th element you start with the head of the list and go down the tower until you find a link that jumps over no more then k elements. You go to the node pointed to by this node and decrease k with the number of elements you have jumped over. Continue doing that until you have k = 0.

Comment: I was also thinking amond the lines of skip-list, can you please elaborate how you modify the access-linked lists [those who guarantee the `O(logn)` search] after inserting an element in an arbitrary location? Won't it cause a need to change a lot of them? I believe it [skip-list] can be modified to fit here, but this point should be elaborated IMO

Comment: No in fact the way i have implemented skip list a while ago you never change the hight of a node. This relies on the fact that if you insert each new node with uniformly distributed height the heights of the elements will be close enough to the perfect ones. There were some analysis on the internet on the amortized complexity of this approach that show it is not much worse then the best possible.

Comment: What I do not understand is how to modify not the height, but also indices, how can you tell the element is the k'th? If your "keys" are the indices, won't each arbitrary insertion requires changing the entire tail of the linked list? [it's not the height that worries me, using non-deterministic linked list solves this issue neatly]

Comment: For each element you have a tower on links to next elements, right? For each link you know how many elements does it jump over. So looking for the k-th element you start with the head of the list and go down the tower until you find a link that jumps over no more then k elements. You go to a new node and decrease k with the number of elements you have jumped over. Continue doing that until you have k = 0.

Comment: Great, that explains it perfectly. +1. I suggest adding this explanation to the answer itself. [actually, I know feel dumb for asking, it is very similar to the idea of maintaining index in a BST by adding a "numberOfSons" field to each node]

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using `std::map`  or `std::vector` ?

You could use a `std::map` with the rank of insertion as key. And [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) has a `reserve` member function.

Comment: The OP wants faster then linear arbitrary insert, won't vector and map be both O(n)?

Comment: Yes, `std::vector` insertion to position `i` will be O(`n`) because the elements `i` through `n` need to be be shifted. With `std::map`, something similar occurs because keys have to be updated.

Comment: @Yavar: But you will have to modify the indices of all the following elements after each insert. assume you had the map=[(1,a),(2,b),(3,c)] and you want to add z in location 0, you will need to modify the map to [(1,z),(2,a),(3,b),(4,c)]. If there is a workaround - it should be elaborated..

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, but it enforces unique keys. You need to do extra work to keep allow multiple insertions to the same index without wiping previous elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `std::map` mapping (index, insertion-time) pairs to values, where insertion-time is an "autoincrement" integer (in SQL terms). The ordering on the pairs should be

```
(i, t) < (i*, t*)
```

iff

```
i < i* or t > t*
```

In code:

```
struct lt {
    bool operator()(std::pair<size_t, size_t> const &x,
                    std::pair<size_t, size_t> const &y)
    {
        return x.first < y.first || x.second > y.second;
    }
};

typedef std::map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, int, lt> array_like;

void insert(array_like &a, int value, size_t i)
{
    a[std::make_pair(i, a.size())] = value;
}
```

Comment: Suppose we insert 300 at 0, then 100 at 0, then 200 at 1. What should happen: `[]` then `[300]`, then `[100 300]`, then `[100 200 300]`. But what actually happens: `[]`, then `[((0, 1), 300)]`, then `[((0, 2), 100), ((0, 1), 300)]`, so far so good, but then `[((0, 2), 100), ((0, 1), 300), ((1, 3), 200)]`. The conclusion: without order statistics, this type of thing is usually hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment:

> List.Insert() (which is too slow as it has to shift every element over),

Lists don't shift their values, they iterate over them to find the location you want to insert, be careful what you say. This can be confusing to newbies like me.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that's included with GCC by default is the **rope** data structure. Here is the [documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html). Typically, ropes come to mind when working with long strings of characters. Here we have `int`s instead of characters, but it works the same. Just use `int` as the template parameter. (Could also be `pair`s, etc.)

Here's the [description of rope on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29).

Basically, it's a binary tree that maintains how many elements are in the left and right subtrees (or equivalent information, which is what's referred to as *order statistics*), and these counts are updated appropriately as subtrees are rotated when elements are inserted and removed. This allows O(lg n) operations.

Answer (score 0):

There's [this](https://medium.com/@igushev/array-with-constant-time-access-and-fast-insertion-and-deletion-c2eef089a25d) data structure which pushes insertion time down from O(N) to O(sqrt(N)) but I'm not that impressed.  I feel one should be able to do better but I'll have to work at it a bit.

Answer (score -1):

In c++ you can just use a map of vectors, like so:

```
int main() {
  map<int, vector<int> > data;
  data[0].push_back(1);
  data[1].push_back(3);
  data[1].push_back(2);
  data[0].push_back(5);
  map<int, vector<int> >::iterator it;
  for (it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) {
    vector<int> v = it->second;
    for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      cout << v[i] << ' ';
    }
  }
  cout << '\n';
}
```

This prints:

```
5 1 2 3
```

Just like you want, and inserts are O(log n).

Comment: It will fail if you next try to push 10 in the 2nd index.